# How can i install latest chromium version in RHEL 7?

Tags: chromium, rhel

Im trying to install latest version of chromium package version 93.x. Currently i have version 90.x installed.

- `sudo yum update chromium`, there is nothing to do.
- Uninstall & install the package does not help
- Im using epel repository

[image]

Note: snap installation is not a solution

Any ideas?

Comment: For what reason do you need the latest version of chromium for RHEL?

Comment: is simply a requirement, would it not be possible?

Comment: I'm asking because I see no reason why someone would use a server OS, which depends on security and stability, and would wrack havoc all of that in favor of some latest buggy beta chromium version. In my opinion it makes no sense. Use the snap version of chromium, as it's a container VM and thus relatively secure.

Comment: Thank you, is there no other way except snap version?

Comment: You could download a precompiled version or compile it by yourself and save this in `/usr/local/...`, but this has to be manually maintained. Otherwise you could create your own package and use the package manager.